# How to create HtmlDropdownListfor in asp.net mvc 5 without use of modelviews in one to many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am a beginner and learning ASP.Net MVC 5 and there are many answers in stack overflow related to my question but I could not find what I was looking for.

So, I have two model. `Car and Company`. **one car can belong 
to one company and one company can have many cars**.
Now I have form named "**Car Entry Form**" where user will see a `textbox` to put car name and a `dropdown list to select company name`.

**Question:** I am able to create a view model and display the form with dropdown of company list. But I just want to know suppose if I am not allowed to use **viewmodel**, in that situation is it possible to show the dropdown list in the Car Entry Form.
**Is it mandatory/preferrable to use viewmodel**, in my above stated scenario. Can I just use car model and somehow incorporate the dropdown list for company? Am I making sense?

**Viewmodel solution**

**Car Model**

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CarName { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

**Company Model**

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Website> Car { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
 public class CarViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CarName { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller Action**

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var viewModel = new CarViewModel
    {
        Companies = _context.Companies.ToList()
    };
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

**Fluent Api**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
                .HasMany<Car>(w => w.Cars)
                .WithRequired(w => w.Company)
                .HasForeignKey(w => w.CompanyId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

**View File**

```
@model WebApplication3.Models.CarFormViewModel
        <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CompanyId, new SelectList(Model.Companies, "Id", "Name", Model.Companies), new { @class = "form-control"})
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `I am not allowed to use viewmodel` Is this a school assignment? Otherwise, using ViewModel could be a lot clear and easy to maintain than using dynamic object like ViewBag.

Comment: Why in the world would you not be allowed to use a view model?. And as a side note, remove the 4th parameter in the `SelectList` constructor (which does nothing) - its just `new SelectList(Model.Companies, "Id", "Name")`, but your property really should be `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Companies ` (not `IEnumerable<Company> Companies`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke:  I thought that 4th parameter is needed if I want to show the first dropdown option by default in the dropdown. And I will change the property to `IEnummerable<SelectListItem>`. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: No. Its ignored when binding to a property (its the value of the property that determines what is selected).

Comment: @StephenMuecke: So I am assuming if I follow what you have told then when the page reloads I will have the first options set on the dropdown. Also, after making IEnummerable<SelectListItem> Companies. Now my Controller action is throwing error as "Cannot convert generic list to ienummerable. "

Comment: If you have changed the property it would be `var viewModel = new CarViewModel { Companies = _context.Companies.Select(x => new SelectListItem{ Value = x.Id.ToString(), Text = x.CompanyName }) };` (and in the view `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CompanyId, Model.Companies, new { ... })`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I will follow what you told and will try to implement it. But creating a dropdown like this has been taught to me in Pluralisght video tutorial by Mosh Hamedani (in his ASP.Net MVC 5 series).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151754/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-unbreakable).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

I often use approach like this:

Your action should be like this:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Companies = _context.Companies.ToList();
    return View();
}
```

And Here is Your View:

```
@model WebApplication3.Models.Car
    <div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-10">
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CompanyId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Companies as List<WebApplication3.Models.Company>, "Id", "Name", Model.Companies), new { @class = "form-control"})
</div>
```

**ViewBag** is dynamic object and it is used to pass objects form controller to the view.

can find more about ViewBag [here](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/viewbag-in-asp.net-mvc).

And I belive when you are creating a view to edit `Car` Model its ViewModel should be `Car` and a **CompanyList** is not a part of a Car it's something that just help user to edit car. you know, you just need a CompanyId for editing or creating a Car so it's better to don't use it as part of ViewModel. But feel free and find your best practices and approaches. there is no rule to how separate your objects that want to pass to view.